# onKeyUp/onKeyDown doesn't work in Anroid after overriding?

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I tried to rewrite these three methods in order to print out the log on the console, but after running the program, I found that there is only a log about method `onTouchEvent()` after clicking the button. The other two methods:`onKeyDown()`and`onKeyUp()` don't seem to work. I am a newcomer to Android, I am very grateful for any help. Does this mean that `onKeyDown()`and`onKeyUp()` are override incorrectly?
The following is the MyButton class：

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton;

public class MyButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private static String TAG = "TAG_";

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        Log.i(TAG, "onKeyDown is been called");
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);

        Log.i(TAG, "onKeyUp is been called");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        Log.i(TAG, "onTouchEvent is been called");
        return true;

    }
}
```

Here are activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.learncallback.MyButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`KeyEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) is a signal from an IME or a physical keyboard to a view. If you want to handle touch events, you should override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` - which you already did - to receive touch information.

I assume you want to track whether the view is being touched or not. For that you need to parse the `MotionEvent` passed to `onTouchEvent` because the framework will call this method whenever a touch event occurs on that view (as long as the parent doesn't intercept it using [onInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))).

React to touch events in `onTouchEvent` using:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    switch (e.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // View being pressed down on
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // View being pressed down on
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // View not touched anymore
        // ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that you will receive touch events other that `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`  only if you return `true` from the initial call to `onTouchEvent`.

Comment: I got you point ,and the switch-case works very well in `onTouchEvent()`. Wether Key presses in software keyboards  generally do NOT trigger the listener of onKeyDown , which is provided to the hardware keyboard insteaed?